# Accessing nested headers with Spring Expression Language (SpEL)

Tags: apache-camel, spring-el

My Camel route needs to access kafka.HEADERS headers from the inbound exchange object. One of the headers is further a List of headers wherein value type is RecordHeader. I want to access one of the RecordHeader (e.g. leadEquipmentId) and compare it with a String. Please can someone suggest how to do so? This syntax is not working:

```
<spel>#{#{request.headers['kafka.HEADERS']}['leadEquipmentId']} == 'SomeEquipmentId'</spel>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RecordHeaders` is not a `Map` so you can't use the `MapAccessor` (`['leadEquipmentId']`).

Try

```
#{new String(request.headers['kafka.HEADERS'].lastHeader('leadEquipmentId').value())} == 'SomeEquipmentId'
```

Comment: Actually that will return the `RecordHeader`, you need its `value()` see the edit.

Comment: I worked out the solution after your first guidance and came up with .value() to be used. While posting the solution I worked out, found that you have also suggested the same. ````<spel>#{request.headers['kafka.HEADERS'].lastHeader('leadEquipmentId').value()} == 'SomeEquipmentId'</spel>````

Comment: Slight syntax update for those who may refer to it at some point in time ````#{new String(request.headers['kafka.HEADERS'].lastHeader('leadEquipmentId').value()) == 'SomeEquipmentId'}```` That is, the position of curly braces should cover the entire expression to be evaluated.